# MVVM call async method on selection change

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a simple list box with selected Item binded to ViewModel's property

```
<ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

and I have an async method that I want to run when the selection changed

```
async Task foo();
```

I could put this call inside the setter for `SelectedItem` but that's a code smell to me.

```
public object SelectedItem
{
    get{...}
    set
    {
         foo(); //Compiler warning and blocks UI
         ...
    }
}
```

`Task.Run` inside set is an option, but still looks bad to me and exception thrown by `foo` will be swollen

Code behind `SelectionChanged` event might be another option but whats the most MVVM way to solve this problem?

Comment: I'd use an async SelectedChanged event handler that calls an async method in the DataContext.

Comment: @Clemens as a MVVM puriest I want to minimize the use of code behind

Comment: The minimum code behind would be `await ((ViewModel)DataContext).SomeAsyncMethod(listBox.SelectedItem);`

Comment: @Clemens let me rephrase it. Empty code behind would be my ultimate goal ..

Comment: @Clemens was hoping for a way to do this with Interaction + action

Comment: You'd at least need an async command then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the approach with zero code behind, here is what I would do.

Convert the SelectedItemChanged event to a command using Interaction.

Here is code on how you can convert an event to a command

```
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SomeEvent">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=SomeCommand, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Your command in the view model will then block the UI and invoke the async functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I would set up an event handler.

something like

```
 public class ViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public ViewModel()
    {
        PropertyChanged += SelectedItemChanged;
    }

    private async void SelectedItemChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(SelectedItem))
        {
            await Foo();
        }
    }

    public Task Foo()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var a = "B";
        });
    }

    private object _selectedItem;

    public object SelectedItem
    {
        get=> _selectedItem;
        set
        {
            if (value != _selectedItem)
            {
                _selectedItem = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```